# Show popup window from console

Tags: batch-file, cmd, dos

Is possible to show a popup/alert in a Batch file?

I've been reading about vb scripting usage, but it is totally necessary?

http://ss64.com/vb/popup.html or http://ss64.com/vb/msgbox.html

Comment: Could you finally decide which one is the Best answer for you? I can't resist your frequent changes! `;-)`. As a general rule, I suggest you to wait _two days_ at least (two more days in weekends) before select the Best answer. Then, select the answer that contributed most to solve the problem _as you posted it_, not any other related/similar/new problem that could have presented meanwhile...

Comment: aacini sorry if I bothered you really both answers are great and helped me to discover new things, I decided to select your answer before I seen the serenity's update which provides more info and then i selected him answer not only because that extra effort but also because he is new and I think new users needs some kind of motivation in that way than you but i like both answers and i hope that you could still help me on my future questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use a Batch-JScript hybrid script, that ultimately it is a .BATch file; for example:

```
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then

@echo off

CScript //nologo //E:JScript "%~F0" "Hi, there..." 
goto :EOF

@end

WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Popup(WScript.Arguments(0));
```

Copy previous code into a file with .bat extension and execute it. The Popup may also include selection buttons, and the result may be get from the Batch code. For example:

```
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then

@echo off

rem Define values for Popup buttons
set /A YesNoAndCancel=3, QuestionMark=32
set /A YesButton=6, NoButton=7, TimedOut=-1

rem Call Popup JScript method with a 7 second timeout.
set /A buttons=YesNoandCancel + QuestionMark
CScript //nologo //E:JScript "%~F0" "Do you feel alright?" "Answer please:" %buttons% 7
set btn=%errorlevel%
if %btn% equ %YesButton% (
   echo Glad to hear you feel alright.
) else if %btn% equ %NoButton% (
   echo Hope you're feeling better soon.
) else if %btn% equ %TimedOut% (
   echo Is there anybody out there?
)
goto :EOF

@end

var arg = WScript.Arguments;
WScript.Quit(WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Popup(arg(1),arg(3),arg(0),arg(2)));
```

For further details about JScript Popup method, see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x83z1d9f(v=vs.84).aspx).

Answer (score 2):

VBScript is not necessary. You can use any programming language (Powershell/Jscript/Any .NET language) except batch.

this one line VBS script does a message box

```
msgbox wscript.Arguments(0)
```

To use

```
"C:\Users\User\Desktop\MsgBox.vbs" "Hi there"
```

**InputBox**

Puts what user entered in a variable `%Filter_InputBox%`

Type `set f` to see results

You need to put own paths in

To use

```
batchfile.bat "Text", "Window Title" "Default text"
```

Remember you must `call` a batch file if you want control to return to another batch

```
call batchfile.bat "Text", "Window Title" "Default text"
```

*VBS File*

```
'Create a batchfile that filter.bat will run as last step to set the environmental variable %Filter_InputBox%.
Text=InputBox(Wscript.Arguments(0), Wscript.Arguments(1),Wscript.Arguments(2))

Set Fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set File = Fso.CreateTextFile("FilterExit.bat", True)
If err.number <> 0 then
    Wscript.echo "Error: " & err.number & " " & err.description & " from " & err.source
    err.clear
    wscript.exit
End If
File.WriteLine "set Filter_InputBox=" & Text
File.close
```

*Batch File*

```
InputBox.vbs %*
If exist "FilterExit.bat" call "FilterExit.bat"
If exist "FilterExit.bat" del "FilterExit.bat"
```